# Datediff in power automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a requirement where in i need to find the date difference between the Date of joining(from the excel sheet which is in sharepoint) and todays date.

[image]

[image]

in the second image(under initialize variable flow), i have written the code as

```
div(sub(ticks(formatDateTime(DOJ,'yyy-MM-dd')),ticks(addDays(utcNow(),-1))),864000000000)
```

but getting as invalid expression.

please help in this

Thanks,
Savitha

Comment: What’s DOJ? Is that a variable?

Comment: What is `DOJ` in this case, is it a column name in SharePoint list? Did you use the "initialize variable" action inside "Appy to each" loop or outside?

Comment: @GaneshSanap you can't use it inside.  It won't let you.

Answer (score 0):

DOJ is a data and time column in your list ,right?
Try to use this the code:

```
div(sub(ticks(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyy-MM-dd')),ticks(item()?['DOJ'])),864000000000)
```

Comment: Hi @Savitha,I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If I misunderstand something, please let me know! If there is any other assistance i can provide, please feel free to let me know, i will do our best to help you.